# Inline array concatenation?

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, inline

Is it possible to concatenate an array using inline code (i.e. inside the array declaration)?
For instance:

```
function get_array() {
    return array('four' => 4, 'five' => 5);
}

$arr = array(
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 3,
    get_array()
);

var_dump($arr);
```

will result in:

```
Array(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
    [0] => Array(
        [four] => 4
        [five] => 5
    )
)
```

Whereas the desired result would be:

```
Array(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
    [four] => 4
    [five] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/array_merge). It is an extra step but since you can't do this during the array declaration it is the next best thing.

```
$new_array = array_merge($arr, array('four' => 4, 'five' => 5));

print_r($new_array);
Array ( [one] => 1 [two] => 2 [three] => 3 [four] => 4 [five] => 5 )
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/05ewnm)

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to do so within the initial array declaration?

Comment: @YoavKadosh: No it is not.  You could also try the ["array union"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (`+`) operator: `$array = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2) + array('three' => 3);`

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's exactly what I was looking for. If you want, you can post that as an answer and i'll accept it (sorry John... :) ).

Comment: @YoavKadosh: That's the same thing as `array_merge` except it has a different behavior when it comes to duplicate keys.